# New-SPServiceApplicationPool does not create IIS application pool

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, administration, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a weird problem on two different environments and I can't figure out what is wrong.

When I run this command `New-SPServiceApplicationPool new_pool -Account domain\spservice` it throws no errors, but new application pool in IIS does not appear.

If I run `Get-SPServiceApplicationPool` it lists this application pool, but it's still not visible in IIS.

I have also noticed that when I create new Service Applications like Managed Metadata and Secure store service - New WCF endpoints do not appear in "SharePoint Web Services" IIS Site.

Something is seriously wrong, but I don't understand what. Something prevents SharePoint from creating IIS artifacts.

ULS and Windows Event logs have no information about this problem at all. Except, for maybe `SPEndpointAddressNotFoundException: There are no addresses available for this application.`. But this is useless, because I know that IIS is missing the endpoints/and application pools, but there is no explanation as to why this is happening.

I wold greatly appreciate any help.

**Update:**

I've just tested how it is supposed to work with SharePoint 2013. When I run `New-SPServiceApplicationPool`, it only creates a new pool and a WCF endpoint inside 'SharePoint Web Services' IIS website when service on server is activated. There is no "Start" and "Stop" button in SP2016, but It says "started" against "Managed Metadata Service". Maybe I can stop and start it with PowerShell somehow and see if it helps...

**Update #2**

I've actually found "start" and "stop" buttons in SP2016. They are moved to System Settings--> Manage services on server. Turns out, that Managed Metadata and Secure store services were actually stopped... Even thougn it said "started" in the Central Admin home --> "Manage services in this farm". After I've started the services all missing Pools and endpoints in IIS were created within a few seconds

Comment: Is the SharePoint Admin Windows Service in a running state? This service is responsible for provisioning.

Comment: Yes, it does :( on both SharePoint farms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, that Managed Metadata and Secure store services were actually stopped... Even thougn it said "started" in the Central Admin home --> "Manage services in this farm". After I've started the services all missing Pools and endpoints in IIS were created within a few seconds